# Swift: Embed a scrollView in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am working on this UITableViewCell customization to get something similar to a Facebook feed look.

I need a cell to contain 2 labels followed by a scroll view(to display some images). I have tried with having these 3 elements inside a uiView as such,

-Cell

--contentView

---UIView

----Label

----Label

----ScrollView

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
```

I need the cells to adjust the height based on the length of the text.

Where I am stuck at is where the cell adjusts the height based on the text, but the scrollview that is displayed, is split into two cells.

Needless to say I am new to swift. This is the basic flow of what I have so far in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.dateLabel.text = somedatelabel
cell.contentLabel.text = someContent
let width = cell.scrollView.frame.width
let height = cell.scrollView.frame.height

var mainCardView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.width, cell.frame.height))

    var scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.contentLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.contentLabel.frame.origin.y+cell.contentLabel.frame.height, width, height))
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*2, height)

    var imageOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width , height))
    var imageTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(width, 0, width, height))

    imageOne.image = UIImage(named: "one.jpg")
    imageTwo.image = UIImage(named: "two.jpg")

    scrollview.addSubview(imageOne)
    scrollview.addSubview(imageTwo)
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*2, height)
    scrollview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    mainCardView.addSubview(scrollview)
    cell.cardView = mainCardView
    cell.contentView.addSubview(mainCardView)

    cell.layoutSubviews()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I also added this in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Any suggestions on how to size the cell so that scrollView is part of the contentView?

Comment: can u upload ouput screen shoot and desire screen shoot

Comment: I am not able to post image since I am new. But the expected result is similar to http://www.elirose.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/IMG_8458-199x300.png

Comment: OUTPUT result - http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-09-04_at_12.48.55_AM-Wt8CuYLi.png

Comment: problem is Image view . what you applied for image view aspectToFit or AspectToFill

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I added a contentMode on scrollView. I have tried setting the mode on the two imageViews as well (Fit and Fill) - still get the similar result.

Comment: chintala.ramkumar cal me on skype